# laravel 4.2 get last 10 records

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, adminlte

How to get last 10 records using AdminLTE in Laravel 4.2 from a specific table from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
foo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```